# MySQL installed but nowhere to be found on MacOS Mojave

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed MySQL 5.7 using `homebrew`:

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

As I understand, I am supposed to find mysql in /usr/local or /usr/local/bin but I see that mysql@5.7 was placed in /usr/local/opt.

Ok...so I tried adding that to the path:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

But still when I try to type `mysql` or `mysql@5.7` in the terminal it says "command not found".

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get mysql to become available as a terminal command?

Comment: Anything come up when you `locate mysql`?

Comment: A huge list of things come up. But `whereis mysql` comes up empty.

Comment: `mysql` isn't in your path, so `whereis mysql` won't do anything. Does anything in `locate mysql` look like the correct binary?

Comment: Also, after adding the export to your path I assume you re ran `.bash_profile` or opened a new terminal?